# MVC Razor formCollection get all options from a select

Tags: html, select, razor, formcollection

I have a `<select>` with multiple `<options>`, i pass the selected option to the controller with formCollection and get the value with `formCollection["inputRole"];`. However i also want a list of all the values in the `<select>`. How can i get this data with formCollection?

Comment: I don't think you can...
I think you will need to add the values to the form post values using javascript on the browser/client side. It wouldn't really make any sense if the browser posted all the values back. How would you know which one was selected? That or you could requery the original source of the values on your server...

Are you using jQuery?

Comment: The user can move values between different selects, i need to know how the user has moved around the options and also the selected options in each select. I use jQuery to move options.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a List in your viewmodel to collect the multiple values. A single string type will be populated with the first selected entry.